# How to tag EKS cluster name or external labels to prometheus metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have deployed kube-prometheus-stack through terraform and created external labels in global prometheus configurations.

```
global:
  external_labels:
    clustername: ekscluster
```

How can we tag this cluster name with prometheus metrics or Is there any way to tag EKS cluster name to prometheus metrics.
I have multiple clusters so, I wanted to filter which metrics are related to which cluster. Is there any way or solution for that. your response will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
global:
  external_labels:
    clustername: ekscluster
```

I added external labels to prometheus configurations but Iam new to prometheus so i am not sure how we can tag this label with metrics.